# Hide padding when overflow: hidden

Tags: css, animation, overflow, css-animations, padding

When I want to animate an element from "height: 0" to "height: auto" and I set the element to "height: 0" initially and add "height: auto" in form of a new class which is added on click, I thought I could use overflow: hidden to hide and show the element, but now the padding forces the element to have the height of the padding even though its "height: 0". Some solutions how to hide the padding when I use "overflow: hidden"?

Comment: consider a parent container?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply transitions to "auto" values. Instead you could try transitioning the `max-height` or `transform` property. It depends on what you are trying to accomplish and what your other styles are. I can only speculate because you have not included any code.

[Here is a good article about the options I mentioned and a few others.](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/)